# How to read a text file and produce an alphabetized vocabulary list using Scanner

Tags: java, file-io, input

I'm trying to read a text file and produce an alphabetized vocabulary list using Scanner in Java.

The one error that I'm receiving in Eclipse states that I must return a List of type String. I sort of understand why that error is occurring but unsure how to fix it.

Can anyone explain to me where I'm incorrect?

This is my current code:

```
public List<String> buildVocabulary(String fileName) {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        List<String> vocab = new ArrayList<String>();
        scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
        scanner.useDelimiter("[.,;']+");
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            vocab.add(scanner.next());
        }
        return vocab;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        fail("Got an exception");
    }
    finally {
        if(scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Test I'm trying to pass:

```
@Test
public void testVocabulary() {
    List<String> vocab = builder.buildVocabulary("text.txt");
    assertTrue(vocab.size() == 256);
    assertTrue( vocab.get(0).equals("a"));
    assertTrue( vocab.get(255).equals("younger"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If an exception gets thrown while reading,
the `return vocab` might not get reached.
In this case, the method has nothing to return,
so you need to add a `return` statement.

You could for example move the declaration and initialization of `vocab` outside the `try-catch` and add a `return vocab` at the end of the method.
Or, you could return an empty list `return Collections.emptyList()`.

Btw, you're catching `IOException`, but `FileNotFoundException` would be enough there, and more appropriate.